# What is this word/phrase?

Tags: word

A friend of mine came to me with something from a hidden-object game, which is supposed to be sheet music. What does this mean? [image]

My friend is convinced it is German, but I am unsure. It might be Greek? We can't make out many of the letters, but we know it is solvable.

Comment: **I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided.** —
It looks like you're asking us for help with a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, **[proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259)** is required. Please [edit] to include (at minimum) where this came from—any additional context you can provide is also helpful to solvers—then vote to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "Altdeutsche Tanzmusik" (Old German dance music) to me.